# Node.js + browserify - Error: Cannot find module 'cls-bluebird'

Tags: node.js, browserify

I am trying to run this simple code to run on my browser using a node.js model - using browserify.

test2.js:

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

function get_vars(){

    var keyword = document.getElementById("keyword");
    var limit   = document.getElementById("limit");

    console.log(keyword);
    console.log(limit);

    get_search_results(keyword, limit);

}

function get_search_results(keyword, limit){


    gplay.search({
        term: keyword,
        num: limit
      }).then(console.log, console.log);

}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" />
<input type="text" name="limit" id="limit">

<button onclick="get_vars();">GO!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I run `browserify test2.js -o bundle2.js` on CMD I get this output:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'cls-bluebird' from 'C:\wamp\www\nodetest\node_modules\request-promise\lib'
    at C:\Users\banana\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:46:17
    at process (C:\Users\banana\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:173:43)
    at ondir (C:\Users\banana\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:188:17)
    at load (C:\Users\banana\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:69:43)
    at onex (C:\Users\banana\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:92:31)
    at C:\Users\banana\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:22:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:117:15)
```

Tried installing `npm install bluebird` and nothing isn't changing and I cant find this error anywhere.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cls-bluebird` is defined as a dev dependency of `request-promise` (which in turn is used by `google-play-scraper`).

The way `cls-bluebird` is used in `request-promise` "confuses" Browserify in thinking that it's a regular dependency, so it tries to include it in the generated bundle. But because dev dependencies aren't normally installed during `npm install PACKAGE`, it's missing and you get an error about a missing module.

The easiest solution is to just install `cls-bluebird` manually:

```
$ npm i cls-bluebird
```

That allows Browserify to find it. You can add `--save` if you have your own `package.json`.

Alternatively, you can install `google-play-scraper` with all dev dependencies:

```
$ npm i google-play-scraper --dev
```

However, that will install *all* dev dependencies for *all* the modules on which `google-play-scraper` depends, which makes the installation take a long time.

Comment: Thanks this works! 

but now I get an other error, this time from the console. it doesn't recognize the functions from  the first .js file, 

`Uncaught ReferenceError: get_vars is not definedonclick @ index.html:13` in 

I'm really new to NODE.JS and currently learning on the fly - do you have a recommendation of a good course or tutorials of basic usage of packages and structure? 
The only ones I have found were more technical and less about management.

Comment: for example, I don't really understand what's DEV in node.js which seems kinda important to know (like this example..)

Comment: @RickSanchez I can't recommend anything simply because I don't know what good courses or tutorials are :-( For Browserify, perhaps a good starting point is [this page](http://browserify.org/articles.html) (but I have to say that Browserify is a relatively advanced subject already, you should really have a reasonable understanding of Node to be able to understand what Browserify does and doesn't do). TBH: the issue you ran into is not entirely down to inexperience, it also has to do with the way that `request-promise` is structured, confusing Browserify.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow this steps:

```
npm install --save bluebird

var Promise = require("bluebird");

To enable long stack traces and warnings in node development:

$ NODE_ENV=development node server.js

To enable long stack traces and warnings in node production:

$ BLUEBIRD_DEBUG=1 node server.js

See Environment Variables.
```

From:

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/install.html

You can find similar errors, and different proposition to solve it:

https://github.com/request/request-promise/issues/91

Hope it helps,